(COMPLETED) - Chat upgrade incoming! No feature changes, but major under-the-hood work
Update October 24, 14:30 UTC: The upgrade was successful, we're continuing to keep an eye on things.
Original post:

TL;DR
We'll be deploying a new version of Chat that has significant under-the-hood changes. Ideally you won't notice anything, but just in case, here's what's happening:

✅ status-completed On Wednesday, October 23, around 15:30 UTC, chat.meta gets the new version. I'll be in the Tavern when I deploy the change, so if you notice anything odd, please let me know there, or post a bug report on Meta with bug chat. Of course if I end up breaking Chat, you only have the second option 

⌛ status-review We'll be monitoring for issues both in logs and on Meta. Please click around to see if anything is broken. Well, more broken than usual.

✅ status-completed Assuming all seems well (update: it does), we'll also switch chat.se and chat.so a day later, on Thursday, October 24, around 14:00 UTC.


I'll update this post with any new details (in particular: exact times) as we have them.
TS;WMD (too short, want more details)
About 457 million seconds ago, when I had a lot fewer gray hairs, I was hired to be part of a two-person team that would build a chat platform for the Stack Exchange network.
The initial version of Chat targeted version 3.5 of the .NET Framework (think "standard library" if you're not familiar with the stack.)
On August 3, 2010, at 6:45 UTC, Chat was upgraded to .NET 4.0. Seven minutes later, at 6:52 UTC, that upgrade was rolled back with a commit message that I will not be quoting here.
On August 19, 2010, Chat was upgraded to .NET 4.0 again, this time for good. In September 2012 came .NET 4.5; in April 2018 it was .NET 4.6.2.
And that remained until this year. Yay for stability!
As you all are aware, Chat doesn't get much work put into it these days, but to its credit, it still works quite well given the age of the codebase. We even had AI features all the way back in 2011!
Speaking of AI - I know we've shared a lot about it lately, but there's other important work happening as well. For example, as we announced at the beginning of the year,

Stack Overflow has selected Google Cloud as the platform of choice to host and grow its public facing developer knowledge platform.

And as part of that, to get back to our topic here, we would also like to move Chat to the cloud. That means it should run in a good ol' Docker container, which means it has to run on Linux, which means it can't run on .NET Framework because that's Windows only.
Luckily, Microsoft has long made a new version of the framework called .NET Core. (They eventually dropped the word "Core" from the branding, but I'll use it here for clarity). It's open source, cross-platform, and generally pretty great. We migrated the Q&A app a long time ago, but Chat remained on .NET Framework -- until now.
I spent a lot of time recently on migrating Chat to .NET 8 (which is ".NET Core"), and while it's not moving to the cloud just yet (there will be a separate announcement for that), we still want to deploy the updated version to Chat's current home in our planet-based data center.
That'll allow us to hash out any issues specific to the .NET migration that do not stem from moving to a different operating system and infrastructure.
So that's what the "under-the-hood changes" refer to.
If you see anything breaking once we deploy that new version, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

It's about time we uni-core-nified chat.

@AdamLear I'm not sure meta is an appropriate place for core-ny jokes.

@balpha If we don't allow at least some jokes, it'll just be stuffy and core-porate. It's a NET good.

@Slate I'm just worried that such core-dial chit-chat may make us seem unprofessional.

And you're really really sure that "the hood" isn't a euphemism for "Khazad-dûm"? Hope some of these changes will eventually lead to the possibility for other updates to chat - glad SE has the right person around to work on it.

I shouldn't worry about it, the unicorn will have migrated out of there before the balrog hits.

In the past when there have been major architecture changes like this, the person/team behind them would post to the blog about the experience. Are there any plans for you to do something similar here? It would be interesting to read for us .NET developers.

@TylerH I'm not promising anything, but it's a good idea. I have a few good tips around how I approached this.

Oh man. I missed such posts. I really did, and was afraid they're gone for good, replaced by, well, what we usually get. Thanks!

Also, I believe it's related to this as well?

What about bots? I know the chat internals aren't for external consumption, but there is a significant presence of bots on SE chat these days; will they need a complete rewrite? Or better yet, will you provide an official chat API?

@Seggan A chat API is a pretty significant amount of work and commitment to develop; since the goal is to migrate rather than build new features, to my knowledge, I don't think it's in the cards at the moment. As far as bots go, I'm not aware of anything that should change, if the migration as a whole works. balpha's the expert though, and I defer to him for corrections (only taking this because it's a hair past EOD).


"... rolled back with a commit message that I will not be quoting ..." - thinking we know who that is: "We miss that guy, and his quick fixes.".


@Slate If you open-sourced the chat code on GitHub, I'm sure you could find some volunteers here to create an API for you (or just directly write PRs for the features we want) :-) wink wink, nudge nudge.

Now the important question: Can you quote the commit message here in the comments? :P

Thanks; it was hard to understand what features (none) or functionality this involved; the summary seems to be "Migrating SO Chat from .NET Framework to .NET Core, as a precursor to subsequently moving to Google Cloud/docker container/Linux". Is there any impact? (availability/performance?) Is there any roadmap of feature changes to SO Chat?

@smci "No feature changes" is literally in the title of this question. and the teyt says "Ideally you won't notice anything". I feel like I was setting expectations pretty clearly. So I wonder what you I think I might have done better there? Either way, your summary is spot-on, and I wouldn't expect any impact (exept for maybe during the actual migration -- something always goes wrong )

@balpha: I would have worded it "Chat upgrade incoming, .NET migration! No feature changes, but major under-the-hood work". (Otherwise if there are no feature changes and no performance impact and what's being upgraded isn't summarized either, it's confusing if it's just a note about some refactoring or something). Anyway thanks for the update, I understand it now.

status-completed
Not necessarily broken, but still a change: The title for one-boxed YouTube videos no longer show up when not hovered over.  This somewhat oddly still works for videos linked prior to the update, just not for videos linked afterward.

As for what's been posted before update it's not odd, as the actual content is being stored as the message - the onebox isn't "live" i.e. the HTML of the youtube frame is stored as the chat message, and not the link that was submitted.

Here's a spot in the transcript where this was discovered: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/66492773#66492773

@ShadowWizard that might explain why linking to a previous YouTube one-box still works as expected too.

There appears to be a div of class ob-youtube-title that's missing on youtube onebox'd messages following the update. Example div structure: <div class="ob-youtube-title">(there's a title here that I've manually edited)</div>

Issue found, thanks! It's caused by a change in JSON (de)serialization behavior. Fix coming soon.

@balpha huh! Luckily not Jason. That could have a massive beard. ;-)

Fixed

The fact that it still worked on prior oneboxes is not odd. When a onebox is generated, its HTML is cached indefinitely.
